# Pandas apply unique random number to nan else go to next row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pd as pandas
import random
import numpy as np 

data = {'Item_No':['001', '002', '003','004', '005', '006','007','008','009'], 
        'Group_code':[331, 332, 333, 333, 333, 331, 331, nan, nan]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to apply a unique random number to 'nan' and keep the group code where group code exists.
I've tried the following, but i cant seem to get the syntax right, what am i doing wrong.

```
df['Group_Code'] = df['Group_Code'].apply(lambda v: (random.random() * 1000) if pd.isnull(v['Group_Code'] else v['Group_Code'], axis = 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 0:-**

Your Dataframe:-

```
data = {'Item_No':['001', '002', '003','004', '005', '006','007','008','009'], 
        'Group_code':[331, 332, 333, 333, 333, 331, 331, np.nan, np.nan]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Step 1:-**

Firstly define a function:-

```
def func(val):
    if pd.isnull(val):
        return random.random() * 1000
    else:
        return val
```

**Step 2:-**

Then just use `apply()` method:-

```
df['Group_code']=df['Group_code'].apply(func).astype(int)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output

Comment: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. I'll change column to int type.

Comment: I edited my answer just have a look follow along with steps @amit singh......between if this answer helped you then try considering to accept this answer

Comment: I went with float ;)